# Create a wordpress table at activating a plugin

Tags: plugins, create-table, activation

I have read a bunch a posts about how to create a SQL table for Wordpress, when you "activate" a custom plugin.  However, I am looking at the database and the table is not being created.

How do I create a table using a Wordpress plugin?

The code below is intended to create a table called "PICFCounter" and then populate that table with some initial data using function 'PICFCounter_install_data'.

```
global $PICF_db_version;
$PICF_db_version = '1.0';
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'PICFCounter_install' );
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'PICFCounter_install_data' );
function PICFCounter_install () {       
   global $wpdb;
   global $PICF_db_version;
   $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "PICFCounter";  // Create a prefix for table PICFCounter
   $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
//Check to see if the table exists
   if($wpdb->get_var( "show tables like '$table_name'") != $table_name)
      {
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
                ID int(25) NOT NULL auto_increment,
                City varchar(55) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
                Event_Date date NOT NUll,
                Counter_Value int(56) NOT NULL AUTO_DECREMENT,
                PRIMARY KEY (ID)
                )   $charset_collate;";
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
        dbDelta( $sql );
    }
}
function PICFCounter_install_data() {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "PICFCounter";
    $city = 'Calgary';
    $date =     '2022-01-11';       //date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $c = '25';
    $wpdb->insert( 
            $table_name, 
            array( 
                'City' => $city,
                'Event_Date' => $date,
                'Counter_Value' => $c
        ) 
   );
}
```

Comment: I should mention that the code does run....When I add an echo "comment" line inside each function WordPress tells me there is an unexpected string. .  so the functions are entered and exited....but I cannot see the results of what happened.

Comment: I read somewhere that the activation hook is not called everytime.  Maybe I need to update the version of the plugin and compare it to the plugin already installed.   However, this this functionality would still need to be run everytime the plugin is activated.

Comment: Why is this function not running during plugin activation?